# Python - Basic vs extended slicing

Tags: python, python-2.7

When experimenting with slicing I noticed a strange behavior in Python 2.7:

```
class A:
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        print repr(i)
a=A()
a[:] #Prints slice(0, 9223372036854775807, None)
a[::] #prints slice(None, None, None)
a[:,:] #prints (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, None))
```

When using a single colon in the brackets, the slice object has 0 as start and a huge integer as end. However, when I use more than a single colon, start and stop are None if not specified.

Is this behaviour guaranteed or implementation specific?

The [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#types) says that the second and third case are extended slicing, while the first case is not. However, I couldn't find any clear explanation of the difference between basic and extended slicing.

Are there any other "special cases" which I should be aware of when I override `__getitem__` and want to accept extended slicing??

Comment: With Python 2.7, I get `2147483647` (2^31-1), so the value is definitely system-specific. With Python 3, I get `None` in all cases.

Comment: It also changes to `None` if you make `A` a new-style class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Python 2 `[:]` still calls [`__getslice__(self, i, j)`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) (deprecated) and this is documented to return a slice `slice(0, sys.maxsize, None)` when called with default parameters:

> Note that missing `i` or `j` in the slice expression are replaced by **zero** or **`sys.maxsize`**, ...

(emphasis mine).
New style classes don't implement `__getslice__()` by default, so

> If no `__getslice__()` is found, a slice object is created instead, and passed to `__getitem__()` instead.

Python 3 doesn't support `__getslice__()`, anymore, instead it [constructs a `slice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__length_hint__) object for all of the above slice expressions. And `slice()` has `None` as default:

> Note: Slicing is done exclusively with the following three methods. A call like
>
> `a[1:2] = b`
>
> is translated to
>
> `a[slice(1, 2, None)] = b`
>
> and so forth. Missing slice items are always filled in with `None`.